# How can I replace object values in a efficient way?

Tags: typescript, performance

Like the title says, is there a way to make the below more efficient? The main problem is it's not possible to predict user input however I'm open to alternative ways as long as the usage is kind of the same

```js
import base from "../locale/base.json";
import en from "../locale/en.json";

type Language = keyof typeof languages;

const languages: Record<"en", typeof base> = { en };

export const setLanguage = <T extends Language>(
  lang: T
): ((placholders?: object) => typeof base) => {
  return (placeholders) => {
    let translation = languages[lang];

    for (const [placeholderKey, placeholderValue] of Object.entries(
      placeholders ?? {}
    )) {
      for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(translation)) {
        if (typeof value === "string") {
          translation = {
            ...translation,
            [key]: value.replace(
              new RegExp(`{{${placeholderKey}}}`, "g"),
              placeholderValue
            ),
          };
        }

        if (Array.isArray(value)) {
          translation = {
            ...translation,
            [key]: value.map((val) =>
              val.replace(
                new RegExp(`{{${placeholderKey}}}`, "g"),
                placeholderValue
              )
            ),
          };
        }
      }
    }

    return translation;
  };
};

const x = setLanguage("en");
x().test;
```

Comment: What means "efficient"? Faster? Easier to write and read? if it's about performance, I'd modify objects instead of creating a new instance for every updated property.

Comment: Could you show me a example for this use case? It’s not about readability, I just feel like this won’t perform well because I’m calling this function about every few seconds / minutes and as you can see by the logic it just recreates the object and calls a regexp every iteration, maybe the performance isn’t bad and I’m overthinking it, I do not notice a bad performance at least but I can’t give much insight on that

Comment: I guess the regex is the slowest part. While you could optimize performance by modifying objects instead of creating new instances, it seems that the regex calls are required. Optimizing this would involve questions like... How much data? Can you cache results? do you really need to do this so often? ... but why? It seems that you don't have a problem.